# How to increase the limit of pallet count in runtime?

Tags: pallet, runtime, limit

I found that Substrate has a limit of 64 pallets that can be added to the runtime.
Adding more causes the following (very unobvious) error:

```
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `execute_block` exists for struct `Executive<Runtime, Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, ...>, ..., ..., ..., ...>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
```

[image]

I'm using [this runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node/runtime) as a template.

Is there a way to extend this limitation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are the first one to hit that limit . The compile error comes directly from Rust. Not sure how much we can do to have a nicer print.

`frame-support` exposes multiple [features](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ce2cee35f8f0fc5968ea6ffaffa6660dcd008804/frame/support/Cargo.toml#L79) like `tuples-96` which should enable support for runtimes with more pallets. In your `Cargo.toml` you would additionally enable `frame-support/tuples-96`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly after adding **tuples-96** feature like this:
`frame-support = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.36", features = ["tuples-96"] }`

Comment: Limit has been increased on `master` branch: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13760

Comment: That was done only for the kitchensink runtime - other projects will still need to change their code to avoid it.

Comment: We have also improved the error message that's thrown by `construct_runtime!`: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13763.
It shouldn't be confusing anymore, once the tuple limit needs to be bumped - this should inform us properly from now on.